# ASP automatically inserts CSS into website

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I am using an ASP menu control on my website as a header and have no CSS currently defined for the menu, but for some reason ASP automatically inserts some CSS into my page when the page is loaded and messes up the padding on my menu.

I have searched the entire VS solution for a way to change these css values that are inserted, but cannot find them.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link href="../Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="../Content/css/coin-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Content/javascript/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Content/javascript/cufon-times.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Content/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Content/javascript/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Content/javascript/coin-slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code above is supposed to be there, but the code below is inserted into the `index.aspx`

```
<style type="text/css">
/* <![CDATA[ */
#ctl05 { background-color:Black; }
#ctl05 img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#ctl05 img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
#ctl05 img.horizontal-separator { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#ctl05 ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
#ctl05 ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
#ctl05 a { text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
#ctl05 a.static { padding:18px 45px 18px 45px;text-decoration:none; }
#ctl05 a.popout { background-image:url("/WebResource.axd?d=YAYach_zykzn7tRotFpEUmO1fL8jOiyhzrMCvs8YZwkH3GP7lZCuWXNQruOKzP9a49jEMgtKQl2DkwKanmJIMc3YOWHLj04418ItgeJTIvI1&t=636042698594211026");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right center;padding-right:14px; }
#ctl05 a.dynamic { background-color:Gray;text-decoration:none; }
#ctl05 a.dynamic.highlighted { background-color:Black; }
/* ]]> */
</style>
</head>
```

I dont mind a dirty fix to somehow change the padding-right value on the a.popout to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using your own CSS file/style block can you override whatever properties you need to using `!important` after them?

```
<style>
  #ctl05 ul.dynamic { z-index:99 !important; }
</style>
```

Look under the Cascading Order section for some info on how !important affects the specificity of rules: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade

You can also Google CSS !important. :)

Comment: But ho? for example

    ul.dynamic

Comment: Thanks Dave. I got it.